# Convert c++ object to jobject

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My android app gets `City` (with 2 fields: `int id` and `String name`) from user, sends it to c++ part through `jni`, saves to sqlite. Then in onResume() java side asks c++ side for all cities to show them to user. My problem is how to convert object `City` to jobject. Here is my function where I try to convert cities that c++ retrieved from db to jobjectArray and send them to java:

```
    extern "C"
        jobjectArray Java_com_alla_myweatherndk_MainActivity_getCities(JNIEnv *env, jobject) {
            if (retrieveCityFromDb()) {
                jclass cityClass = env->FindClass("com/alla/myweatherndk/entity/CityWeather");
                if (cityClass == NULL){
                    return NULL;
                }
                CityWeather* cities = getCities();
                jobjectArray javaArray = env->NewObjectArray((sizeof(cities)/sizeof(*cities)), cityClass, NULL);
                env->DeleteLocalRef(cityClass);

                if (javaArray == NULL){
                    return NULL;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(cities)/sizeof(*cities)); ++i) {
    // shows error here, since cities[i] isn't jobject
                    env->SetObjectArrayElement(javaArray, i, cities[i]);
                    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
                        return NULL;
                    }
                }
                return javaArray;
            } else {
                return NULL;
            }
        }
```

Function `getCities()` returns array of all cities from db.

Comment: I dont want to be a party breaker but you are not aware you have more problems than you actually have. For once this: (sizeof(cities)/sizeof(*cities) I am pretty sure it won't work the way you expect it to work.

sizeof(cities) will return size of a pointer, it might vary but it will be 4 or 8 bytes depending on architecture. sizeof(*cities) will be the size of an instance that is pointed to.

Comment: I wonder why you wouldn't want to perform the SQLite stuff directly in the Java code. You should use JNI only where it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: @ChristianHackl it's for educational purpose, to learn how to work using c/c++ with external libraries, of course with java it will be much easier. Plus some companies practies common business logic for android and ios in c++